# Unexpected token '�', "��{}" is not valid JSON while parsing '��{}'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, create-react-app, vite

I'm using Windows 11 and Node 20.10.0 LTS. I'm running into an token error when running any React boilerplate.

The error is as follows:

```
ERROR in ./src/logo.svg
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib/index.js):
JSONError: JSON Error in ...\package.json:
Unexpected token '�', "��{}" is not valid JSON while parsing '��{}'
```

This error happens in Create React App and Vite. The issue does not occur in NextJS. All are latest versions. The templates are unmodified and I'm expecting to see the default landing pages.

Some troubleshooting that I've tried:

- npm cache verify
- npm cache clean --force
- Reinstall Node with v16
- Use CRLF and LF line endings
- Reinstall code editors

I've been confused searching for what this error is caused by. I can't seem to reproduce this error on any other Windows, Mac, or Linux devices.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Might you have a BOM in your package.json file?

Comment: @ewokx I'm not familiar with BOM. I did ensure the encoding is UTF-8 through my editor. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What did you use to create that package.json file?  Try using a different text editor to do that.  Possibly even notepad.

Comment: @ewokx I used npm to create the package.json. So in the case of NextJS I would run `npx create-next-app@latest` in the terminal. I don't use any code editors to create it, just the terminal.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with react, but one option is to just overwrite the ```package.json``` with one that doesn't have the BOM.    simplest would be to ```echo "{}" > package.json```.  There are probably better ways..

Comment: What is the command you are running that leads to the error you are seeing?  And is your package.json truly just an empty object `{}` ?

Comment: @GregFenton I'm running the default `npm start` in the package.json provided by [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts).

Comment: Configure the editor to show all symbols and see if there’s any in the package.json

Comment: Open package.json with your editor and convert its encoding to UTF-8 **without BOM**, and save it. Some Windows editors still place an UTF-8 "byte order mark" at the start of the file to indicate that the file is in UTF-8, but that's not really necessary anymore. If you hexdump/open the file with a hex editor, you can probably see those two extra bytes at the start.

Comment: @eventHandler In VSCode I enabled render all characters and there are no extra white spaces. All is as expected.

Comment: @cbr I opened the package.json file in VSCode and checked; it indicated UTF-8 without BOM. As an extra step, I converted it to UTF-8 without BOM, but there was no change.

To ensure it wasn't just an issue with VSCode, I opened Notepad++ to check the encoding, and it also displayed UTF-8 without BOM. I attempted to re-encode it as UTF-8 without BOM, but there were no changes.

Comment: BTW: if this is a new project, you should be using something that is not CRA.  I recommend Vite but others may have other opinions.

Comment: Can you upload the package.json somewhere?  Maybe ZIP it and upload it?
If you have a BASH shell of some type (e.g. GitBASH) then maybe you could share with us the output of `od -c package.json` ?

Comment: @GregFenton Yes! I mentioned in the post that I have the same issue on Vite as well. I'm using default Windows Powershell so `od` is not a command. However, when I use gitbash (MINGW64) it does show this [https://pastebin.com/V6eZEv7n](https://pastebin.com/V6eZEv7n). Here is the package.json [https://pastebin.com/3yEWzUWk](https://pastebin.com/3yEWzUWk).

Comment: The package.json looks fine based on the `od` output.  Re-reading the error message, it indicates that the error starts with logo.svg ??  Any chance you could upload a failing project to GitHub and share?